# exclude windows phone 8.0 from store upload target 8.1 only

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, target

Experiencing issues with my app on windows phone 8.0 and would like to limit support to 8.1 till those are fixed . Any ideas on how to limit support to 8.1 only?

Comment: You can't limit the version, whenever you go for the 8.1 it'll be compatible with WP8 too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? In your project property page:

[image: Property Page Clip]

Comment: Thanks couldn't see that option on the version of vs that im running will update and try again  . Just need to be 100% sure that the store hides the app from wp8.0 users.

Comment: @K4lp3sh If you publish an app only supports Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8.0 users cannot see this app with searching in store. If they have a link to your app they can view the app info in their stores but they cannot install it with a error message says their device doesn't support the app.